# Stata Not Dropping Variables (in regression) due to Multicollinearity and I think it should

Tags: stata, linear-regression

I am running a simple regression of race times against temperature just to develop some basic intuition. My data-set is very large and each observation is the race completion time of a unit in a given race, in a given year.

For starters I am running a very simple regression of race time on temperature bins.

Summary of temp variable:

```
            |              
Variable    |   Obs     Mean      Std. Dev   Min    Max
------------+--------------------------------------------
avg_temp_scc|  8309434  54.3      9.4         0      89
```

Summary of time variable:

```
Variable    |   Obs     Mean      Std. Dev   Min    Max
------------+--------------------------------------------
chiptime    |  8309434  267.5      59.6     122      1262
```

I decided to make 10 degree bins for temperature and regress time against those.

The code is:

```
    egen temp_trial = cut(avg_temp_scc), at(0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90)
    reg chiptime i.temp_trial
```

The output is

```
  Source |       SS       df       MS              Number of obs = 8309434
---------+------------------------------           F(  8,8309425) =69509.83
   Model |  1.8525e+09     8   231557659           Prob > F      =  0.0000
Residual |  2.7681e+108309425  3331.29368           R-squared     =  0.0627
    -----+--------------------------------           Adj R-squared =  0.0627
   Total |  2.9534e+108309433  3554.22521           Root MSE      =  57.717



     chiptime |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
    ----------+----------------------------------------------------------------
    temp_trial |
           10  |  -26.63549   2.673903    -9.96   0.000    -31.87625   -21.39474
           20  |   10.23883   1.796236     5.70   0.000      6.71827    13.75939
           30  |   -16.1049   1.678432    -9.60   0.000    -19.39457   -12.81523
           40  |  -13.97918   1.675669    -8.34   0.000    -17.26343   -10.69493
           50  |  -10.18371   1.675546    -6.08   0.000    -13.46772   -6.899695
           60  |  -.6865365   1.675901    -0.41   0.682    -3.971243     2.59817
           70  |   44.42869   1.676883    26.49   0.000     41.14206    47.71532
           80  |   23.63064   1.766566    13.38   0.000     20.16824    27.09305
         _cons |   273.1366   1.675256   163.04   0.000     269.8531      276.42
```

So stata correctly drops the one of the bins (in this case 0-10) of temperature.

Now I manually created the bins and ran the regression again:

```
    gen temp0 = 1 if temp_trial==0
    replace temp0 = 0 if temp_trial!=0

    gen temp1 = 1 if temp_trial == 10
    replace temp1 = 0 if temp_trial != 10

    gen temp2 = 1 if temp_trial==20
    replace temp2 = 0 if temp_trial!=20

    gen temp3 = 1 if temp_trial==30
    replace temp3 = 0 if temp_trial!=30

    gen temp4=1 if temp_trial==40
    replace temp4=0 if temp_trial!=40

    gen temp5=1 if temp_trial==50
    replace temp5=0 if temp_trial!=50

    gen temp6=1 if temp_trial==60
    replace temp6=0 if temp_trial!=60

    gen temp7=1 if temp_trial==70
    replace temp7=0 if temp_trial!=70

    gen temp8=1 if temp_trial==80
    replace temp8=0 if temp_trial!=80

    reg chiptime temp0 temp1 temp2 temp3 temp4 temp5 temp6 temp7 temp8
```

The output is:

```
     Source |       SS       df       MS              Number of obs = 8309434
   ---------+------------------------------           F(  9,8309424) =61786.51
      Model |  1.8525e+09     9   205829030           Prob > F      =  0.0000
   Residual |  2.7681e+108309424  3331.29408           R-squared     =  0.0627
    --------+------------------------------           Adj R-squared =  0.0627
      Total |  2.9534e+108309433  3554.22521           Root MSE      =  57.717


--------------------------------------------------------------------------
chiptime |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
---------+----------------------------------------------------------------
   temp0 |  -54.13245   6050.204    -0.01   0.993    -11912.32    11804.05
   temp1 |  -80.76794   6050.204    -0.01   0.989    -11938.95    11777.42
   temp2 |  -43.89362   6050.203    -0.01   0.994    -11902.08    11814.29
   temp3 |  -70.23735   6050.203    -0.01   0.991    -11928.42    11787.94
   temp4 |  -68.11162   6050.203    -0.01   0.991    -11926.29    11790.07
   temp5 |  -64.31615   6050.203    -0.01   0.992     -11922.5    11793.87
   temp6 |  -54.81898   6050.203    -0.01   0.993       -11913    11803.36
   temp7 |  -9.703755   6050.203    -0.00   0.999    -11867.89    11848.48
   temp8 |   -30.5018   6050.203    -0.01   0.996    -11888.68    11827.68
   _cons |    327.269   6050.203     0.05   0.957    -11530.91    12185.45
```

Note the bins are exhaustive of the entire data set and stata is including a constant in the regression and none of the bins are getting dropped. Is this not incorrect? Given that the constant is being included in the regression, shouldn't one of the bins get dropped to make it the "base case"? I feel as though I am missing something obvious here.

Edit: 
Here is a dropbox link for the data and do file: 
It contains only the two variables under consideration. The file is 129 mb. I also have a picture of my output at the link.

Comment: This problem statement would benefit from an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: One thing to check is `assert (temp0+temp1+...+temp8)==1` to confirm that indeed your bins are exhaustive.

Comment: @WilliamLisowski I did the assert and it did not produce any errors. By MVCE do you mean I should create a dataset and a do file that reproduce the error and attach these to the post?

Comment: @WilliamLisowski I have a simple clear do file and data file ready on my end but the data file is 129 mb. I am not really sure how to share it here. Do you know? The error is reproducible on my end when I use this data and do file.

Comment: @WilliamLisowski Added a dropbox link with the data and code. The data is 129 mb. It would be great if you can check it out. Thanks.

Comment: I confirmed your results using Stata 15. I noted that sorting the data by avg_temp_scc before the second regression solved the problem. I believe that precision issues in the calculation of the correlation matrix is causing the test for collinearity to fail to detect it. I suggest you contact Stata Technical Support and report this to them; they will appreciate the MVCE. Meanwhile, you've unintentionally provided another argument in favor of using factor variables instead of manually-created dummy variables. Thank you for posting this problem.

Comment: I agree. Try `reg chiptime temp0-temp8 in 1/99999` and `reg chiptime temp0-temp8 in 1/100000`. This looks like a precision issue.

Comment: @WilliamLisowski Thank you for verifying this. Can you elaborate on what exactly this precision issue is? Does this only cause problems in this multicollinearity issue? Could it be that when I am using factor variables this precision issue may cause my estimates to be wrong?

Comment: Paraphrasing Fermat, the margins of this comment box are too small to contain my explanation. However, unlike Fermat, I can respond to the preceding comment with extended comments posted as an "answer" below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This too is not an answer, but an extended comment, since I'm tired of fighting with the 600-character limit and the freeze on editing after 5 minutes.

In the comment thread on the original post, @user52932 wrote

> Thank you for verifying this. Can you elaborate on what exactly this
>   precision issue is? Does this only cause problems in this
>   multicollinearity issue? Could it be that when I am using factor
>   variables this precision issue may cause my estimates to be wrong?

I want to be unambiguous that the results from the regression using factor variables are as correct as those of any well-specified regression can be.

In the regression using dummy variables, the model was misspecified to include a set of multicollinear variables. Stata is then faulted for failing to detect the multicollinearity.

But there's no magic test for multicollinearity. It's inferred from characteristics of the cross-products matrix. In this case the cross-products matrix represents 8.3 million observations, and despite Stata's use of double-precision throughout, the calculated matrix passed Stata's test and was not detected as containing a multicollinear set of variables. This is the locus of the precision problem to which I referred. Note that by reordering the observations, the accumulated cross-products matrix differed enough so that it now failed Stata's test, and the misspecification was detected.

Now look at the results in the original post obtained from this misspecified regression. Note that if you add 54.13245 to the coefficients on each of the dummy variables and subtract the same amount from the constant, the resulting coefficients and constant are identical to those in the regression using factor variables. This is the textbook definition of the problem with multicollinearity - not that the coefficient estimates are wrong, but that the coefficient estimates are not uniquely defined.

In a comment above, @user52932 wrote

> I am unsure what Stata is using as the base case in my data.

The answer is that Stata used no *base case*; the results are what are to be expected when a set of multicollinear variables is included among the independent variables.

So this question is a reminder to us that statistical packages like Stata cannot *infallibly* detect multicollinearity. As it turns out, that's part of the genius of factor variable notation, I realize now. With factor variable notation, you tell Stata to create a set of dummy variables that by definition will be multicollinear, and since it understands that relationship between the dummy variables, it can eliminate the multicollinearity *ex ante*, before constructing the cross-products matrix, rather than attempt to infer the problem *ex post*, using the cross-products matrix's characteristics.

We should not be surprised that Stata occasionally fails to detect multicollinearity, but rather gratified that it does as well as it does at doing so. After all, the second model is indeed a misspecification, which constitutes an unambiguous violation of the assumptions of OLS regression on the user's part.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be an "answer" but it's too long for a comment, so I write it here.

My results are different. At the final regression, one variable is dropped:

```
. clear all

. set obs 8309434
number of observations (_N) was 0, now 8,309,434

. set seed 1

. gen avg_temp_scc = floor(90*uniform())

. egen temp_trial = cut(avg_temp_scc), at(0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90)

. gen chiptime = rnormal()

. reg chiptime i.temp_trial

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   = 8,309,434
-------------+----------------------------------   F(8, 8309425)   =      0.88
       Model |  7.07729775         8  .884662219   Prob > F        =    0.5282
    Residual |   8308356.5 8,309,425  .999871411   R-squared       =    0.0000
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =   -0.0000
       Total |  8308363.58 8,309,433    .9998713   Root MSE        =    .99994

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    chiptime |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
  temp_trial |
         10  |   .0010732   .0014715     0.73   0.466    -.0018109    .0039573
         20  |   .0003255   .0014713     0.22   0.825    -.0025581    .0032092
         30  |   .0017061   .0014713     1.16   0.246    -.0011776    .0045897
         40  |   .0003128   .0014717     0.21   0.832    -.0025718    .0031973
         50  |   .0007142   .0014715     0.49   0.627    -.0021699    .0035983
         60  |   .0021693   .0014716     1.47   0.140    -.0007149    .0050535
         70  |  -.0008265   .0014715    -0.56   0.574    -.0037107    .0020577
         80  |  -.0005001   .0014714    -0.34   0.734    -.0033839    .0023837
             |
       _cons |  -.0006364   .0010403    -0.61   0.541    -.0026753    .0014025
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. * "qui tab temp_trial, gen(temp)" is more convenient than "forv ..."
. forv k = 0/8 {
  2. gen temp`k' = temp_trial==`k'0
  3. }

. reg chiptime temp0-temp8
note: temp6 omitted because of collinearity

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   = 8,309,434
-------------+----------------------------------   F(8, 8309425)   =      0.88
       Model |  7.07729775         8  .884662219   Prob > F        =    0.5282
    Residual |   8308356.5 8,309,425  .999871411   R-squared       =    0.0000
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =   -0.0000
       Total |  8308363.58 8,309,433    .9998713   Root MSE        =    .99994

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    chiptime |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       temp0 |  -.0021693   .0014716    -1.47   0.140    -.0050535    .0007149
       temp1 |  -.0010961   .0014719    -0.74   0.456     -.003981    .0017888
       temp2 |  -.0018438   .0014717    -1.25   0.210    -.0047282    .0010407
       temp3 |  -.0004633   .0014717    -0.31   0.753    -.0033477    .0024211
       temp4 |  -.0018566   .0014721    -1.26   0.207    -.0047419    .0010287
       temp5 |  -.0014551   .0014719    -0.99   0.323      -.00434    .0014298
       temp6 |          0  (omitted)
       temp7 |  -.0029958   .0014719    -2.04   0.042    -.0058808   -.0001108
       temp8 |  -.0026694   .0014718    -1.81   0.070     -.005554    .0002152
       _cons |   .0015329   .0010408     1.47   0.141    -.0005071    .0035729
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The difference with yours is: (i) different data (I generated random numbers), (ii) I used a `forvalue` loop instead of manual variable creation. Yet, I see no errors in your codes.

Comment: Thanks. I feel as though something weird is happening in my data then , though I am not sure what. I even tried to predict values and then see that what observations are driving the baseline average (or the regression constant) and the predicted values have a max at 317.5, which is less than 327 (the value of the constant in my regression). I am unsure what Stata is using as the base case in my data.

Comment: Added a link to the main post with the data and code. It would be great if you can check it out. Thanks.

Comment: This is indeed weird. I've posted a comment to your posting.